# checkbox checker wont work in a table. code works without the table tag

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I just dont see the problem. it does exactly what is has to do when you remove the

```
 <table> </table>
```

tags. please take a look at it. maybe im just not seeing the problem.
java:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="all"],input[name="title"]').bind('click', function(){
var status = $(this).is(':checked');
$('input[type="checkbox"]', $(this).parent('li')).attr('checked', status);
});

});
```

html/php:

```
<table border= "1px"; >
<?php   

 echo " 
</ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 <tr><td width='20%'><strong>bird:</strong></td><td width='72%'></td><td width='5%'><li><input type='checkbox' name='title' id='title_1' /> </td>
";

echo '<ul>';
echo
"<tr><td width='20%'><strong>t feather:</strong></td><td  width='72%'>line_of_text</td><td width='5%'><li><input type='checkbox'  name='feathers[0]' id='box_1' value='_1' /></li> </td>";
echo
"<tr><td width='20%'><strong>t feather:</strong></td><td width='72%'>line_of_text</td><td width='5%'><li><input type='checkbox' name='feathers[0]' id='box_1' value='_1' /></li> </td>";
 echo 
    "   
</ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
      <tr><td width='20%'><strong>bird:</strong></td><td width='72%'></td><td width='5%'><li><input type='checkbox' name='title' id='title_1' /> </td>
        ";

   echo '<ul>';
  echo
   "<tr><td width='20%'><strong>t feather:</strong></td><td    width='72%'>line_of_text</td><td width='5%'><li><input type='checkbox' name='feathers[0]' id='box_1' value='_1' /></li> </td>";
echo
"<tr><td width='20%'><strong>t feather:</strong></td><td width='72%'>line_of_text</td><td width='5%'><li><input type='checkbox' name='feathers[0]' id='box_1' value='_1' /></li> </td>";

?>
</table>
```

Comment: It is better to share parsed `HTML`..Difficult to guess the value of `$feathers`

Comment: This doesn't matter, dear Rayon.

Comment: and OP, you can't have li inside tables like that. Only inside `td`

Comment: @PhiterFernandes, It does matter a lot...i can not just run it in any environment..If the question is related with `HTML/CSS/JS/JQ` many would like to execute it in browser environment..With this nested `<?php`, it is not readable...

Comment: The value of the variables doesn't matter. Of course raw HTML is better, but the values doesn't matter.

Comment: the problem starts when you delete the table tags... it has to work with them. i realy dont know how to fix it.

Comment: the value of the variables can be normal words. its about getting the table with checkboxes in wich you can check a specific group of checkboxes .

Answer (score 0):

You are closing not opened tags.

```
<aTag><aSecondTag></aTag><aSecondTag>
```

is incorrect.

```
<aTag><aSecondTag><aSecondTag></aTag>
```

is correct

In your question:

```
<tablet></ul></li></table>
```

This is either unintentional, or just a mistake. Most HTML parsers will not indicate an error, but at the same time, wont render correctly.

Finally, you are even closing `list-item <li>` after the list itself (`<ul> or <ol>`)

Comment: ehm... still cant get it to work even if i close the tags

Comment: read your DOM, check the tags hierarchy. Most likely you already have a wrong "context" before the table.... edit your question, paste the HTML response you are receiving (with headers as well)

Comment: i removed the variables. i challenge you to get it working :D because (u should test by removing the table tag to see what it has to do) i cant get it to work in the table. i removed the variables so you can copy/paste the code.

Comment: And I'll say it again: Starting a closed tag makes no semantic sense.... either post your HTML response, or try to draw what you expect as a result.. You want a table with un-ordered list inside it? [like this?](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_elements)

Comment: [like this](http://imgur.com/RdXOtum) but whenever you select a bird, the feathers must be checked too(only the ones until the next bird in the table).

Comment: That is a different question isnt it? You asked `$('input[type="checkbox"]', $(this).parent('li')).attr('checked', status);`, meaning that if you check the parent of that list item. Add the same Jquery for the `<table>` -> list-type `<ul>/<ol>` ->`<li>`

Comment: it is not? it is a screenshot from the code above. and changing the list type does not work. please try the code and you will understand my problem :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105711/discussion-between-owndbymeg-and-bonatti).